# Post Spring Boot 3 update - Unable to instantiate factory class [org.springframework.cloud.config.client.ConfigServerConfigDataLocationResolver]

Tags: java, spring-boot, logging, spring-cloud

I've updated backend service to use latest Spring Boot 3, however after update, SB application fails due to some issues with setting up deferred logs during config load. Could anyone help with the idea what might be wrong, below is the stack trace:

```
java.lang.IllegalArgumentException: Unable to instantiate factory class [org.springframework.cloud.config.client.ConfigServerConfigDataLocationResolver] for factory type [org.springframework.boot.context.config.ConfigDataLocationResolver]
    at org.springframework.core.io.support.SpringFactoriesLoader$FailureHandler.lambda$throwing$0(SpringFactoriesLoader.java:650)
    at org.springframework.core.io.support.SpringFactoriesLoader$FailureHandler.lambda$handleMessage$3(SpringFactoriesLoader.java:674)
    at org.springframework.core.io.support.SpringFactoriesLoader.instantiateFactory(SpringFactoriesLoader.java:231)
    at org.springframework.core.io.support.SpringFactoriesLoader.load(SpringFactoriesLoader.java:206)
    at org.springframework.core.io.support.SpringFactoriesLoader.load(SpringFactoriesLoader.java:160)
    at org.springframework.boot.context.config.ConfigDataLocationResolvers.<init>(ConfigDataLocationResolvers.java:66)
    at org.springframework.boot.context.config.ConfigDataEnvironment.createConfigDataLocationResolvers(ConfigDataEnvironment.java:160)
    at org.springframework.boot.context.config.ConfigDataEnvironment.<init>(ConfigDataEnvironment.java:148)
    at org.springframework.boot.context.config.ConfigDataEnvironmentPostProcessor.getConfigDataEnvironment(ConfigDataEnvironmentPostProcessor.java:101)
    at org.springframework.boot.context.config.ConfigDataEnvironmentPostProcessor.postProcessEnvironment(ConfigDataEnvironmentPostProcessor.java:96)
    at org.springframework.boot.context.config.ConfigDataEnvironmentPostProcessor.postProcessEnvironment(ConfigDataEnvironmentPostProcessor.java:89)
    at org.springframework.boot.env.EnvironmentPostProcessorApplicationListener.onApplicationEnvironmentPreparedEvent(EnvironmentPostProcessorApplicationListener.java:109)
    at org.springframework.boot.env.EnvironmentPostProcessorApplicationListener.onApplicationEvent(EnvironmentPostProcessorApplicationListener.java:94)
    at org.springframework.context.event.SimpleApplicationEventMulticaster.doInvokeListener(SimpleApplicationEventMulticaster.java:176)
    at org.springframework.context.event.SimpleApplicationEventMulticaster.invokeListener(SimpleApplicationEventMulticaster.java:169)
    at org.springframework.context.event.SimpleApplicationEventMulticaster.multicastEvent(SimpleApplicationEventMulticaster.java:143)
    at org.springframework.context.event.SimpleApplicationEventMulticaster.multicastEvent(SimpleApplicationEventMulticaster.java:131)
    at org.springframework.boot.context.event.EventPublishingRunListener.multicastInitialEvent(EventPublishingRunListener.java:136)
    at org.springframework.boot.context.event.EventPublishingRunListener.environmentPrepared(EventPublishingRunListener.java:81)
    at org.springframework.boot.SpringApplicationRunListeners.lambda$environmentPrepared$2(SpringApplicationRunListeners.java:64)
    at java.base/java.lang.Iterable.forEach(Iterable.java:75)
    at org.springframework.boot.SpringApplicationRunListeners.doWithListeners(SpringApplicationRunListeners.java:118)
    at org.springframework.boot.SpringApplicationRunListeners.doWithListeners(SpringApplicationRunListeners.java:112)
    at org.springframework.boot.SpringApplicationRunListeners.environmentPrepared(SpringApplicationRunListeners.java:63)
    at org.springframework.boot.SpringApplication.prepareEnvironment(SpringApplication.java:352)
    at org.springframework.boot.SpringApplication.run(SpringApplication.java:303)
    at org.springframework.boot.test.context.SpringBootContextLoader.lambda$loadContext$3(SpringBootContextLoader.java:137)
    at org.springframework.util.function.ThrowingSupplier.get(ThrowingSupplier.java:59)
    at org.springframework.util.function.ThrowingSupplier.get(ThrowingSupplier.java:47)
    at org.springframework.boot.SpringApplication.withHook(SpringApplication.java:1386)
    at org.springframework.boot.test.context.SpringBootContextLoader$ContextLoaderHook.run(SpringBootContextLoader.java:543)
    at org.springframework.boot.test.context.SpringBootContextLoader.loadContext(SpringBootContextLoader.java:137)
    at org.springframework.boot.test.context.SpringBootContextLoader.loadContext(SpringBootContextLoader.java:108)
    at org.springframework.test.context.cache.DefaultCacheAwareContextLoaderDelegate.loadContextInternal(DefaultCacheAwareContextLoaderDelegate.java:183)
    at org.springframework.test.context.cache.DefaultCacheAwareContextLoaderDelegate.loadContext(DefaultCacheAwareContextLoaderDelegate.java:117)
    at org.springframework.test.context.support.DefaultTestContext.getApplicationContext(DefaultTestContext.java:127)
    at org.springframework.test.context.web.ServletTestExecutionListener.setUpRequestContextIfNecessary(ServletTestExecutionListener.java:192)
    at org.springframework.test.context.web.ServletTestExecutionListener.prepareTestInstance(ServletTestExecutionListener.java:131)
    at org.springframework.test.context.TestContextManager.prepareTestInstance(TestContextManager.java:249)
    at org.springframework.test.context.junit.jupiter.SpringExtension.postProcessTestInstance(SpringExtension.java:138)
    at org.junit.jupiter.engine.descriptor.ClassBasedTestDescriptor.lambda$invokeTestInstancePostProcessors$10(ClassBasedTestDescriptor.java:377)
    at org.junit.jupiter.engine.descriptor.ClassBasedTestDescriptor.executeAndMaskThrowable(ClassBasedTestDescriptor.java:382)
    at org.junit.jupiter.engine.descriptor.ClassBasedTestDescriptor.lambda$invokeTestInstancePostProcessors$11(ClassBasedTestDescriptor.java:377)
    at java.base/java.util.stream.ReferencePipeline$3$1.accept(ReferencePipeline.java:197)
    at java.base/java.util.stream.ReferencePipeline$2$1.accept(ReferencePipeline.java:179)
    at java.base/java.util.ArrayList$ArrayListSpliterator.forEachRemaining(ArrayList.java:1625)
    at java.base/java.util.stream.AbstractPipeline.copyInto(AbstractPipeline.java:509)
    at java.base/java.util.stream.AbstractPipeline.wrapAndCopyInto(AbstractPipeline.java:499)
    at java.base/java.util.stream.StreamSpliterators$WrappingSpliterator.forEachRemaining(StreamSpliterators.java:310)
    at java.base/java.util.stream.Streams$ConcatSpliterator.forEachRemaining(Streams.java:735)
    at java.base/java.util.stream.ReferencePipeline$Head.forEach(ReferencePipeline.java:762)
    at org.junit.jupiter.engine.descriptor.ClassBasedTestDescriptor.invokeTestInstancePostProcessors(ClassBasedTestDescriptor.java:376)
    at org.junit.jupiter.engine.descriptor.ClassBasedTestDescriptor.lambda$instantiateAndPostProcessTestInstance$6(ClassBasedTestDescriptor.java:289)
    at org.junit.platform.engine.support.hierarchical.ThrowableCollector.execute(ThrowableCollector.java:73)
    at org.junit.jupiter.engine.descriptor.ClassBasedTestDescriptor.instantiateAndPostProcessTestInstance(ClassBasedTestDescriptor.java:288)
    at org.junit.jupiter.engine.descriptor.ClassBasedTestDescriptor.lambda$testInstancesProvider$4(ClassBasedTestDescriptor.java:278)
    at java.base/java.util.Optional.orElseGet(Optional.java:364)
    at org.junit.jupiter.engine.descriptor.ClassBasedTestDescriptor.lambda$testInstancesProvider$5(ClassBasedTestDescriptor.java:277)
    at org.junit.jupiter.engine.execution.TestInstancesProvider.getTestInstances(TestInstancesProvider.java:31)
    at org.junit.jupiter.engine.descriptor.ClassBasedTestDescriptor.lambda$before$2(ClassBasedTestDescriptor.java:203)
    at org.junit.platform.engine.support.hierarchical.ThrowableCollector.execute(ThrowableCollector.java:73)
    at org.junit.jupiter.engine.descriptor.ClassBasedTestDescriptor.before(ClassBasedTestDescriptor.java:202)
    at org.junit.jupiter.engine.descriptor.ClassBasedTestDescriptor.before(ClassBasedTestDescriptor.java:84)
    at org.junit.platform.engine.support.hierarchical.NodeTestTask.lambda$executeRecursively$6(NodeTestTask.java:148)
    at org.junit.platform.engine.support.hierarchical.ThrowableCollector.execute(ThrowableCollector.java:73)
    at org.junit.platform.engine.support.hierarchical.NodeTestTask.lambda$executeRecursively$8(NodeTestTask.java:141)
    at org.junit.platform.engine.support.hierarchical.Node.around(Node.java:137)
    at org.junit.platform.engine.support.hierarchical.NodeTestTask.lambda$executeRecursively$9(NodeTestTask.java:139)
    at org.junit.platform.engine.support.hierarchical.ThrowableCollector.execute(ThrowableCollector.java:73)
    at org.junit.platform.engine.support.hierarchical.NodeTestTask.executeRecursively(NodeTestTask.java:138)
    at org.junit.platform.engine.support.hierarchical.NodeTestTask.execute(NodeTestTask.java:95)
    at java.base/java.util.ArrayList.forEach(ArrayList.java:1511)
    at org.junit.platform.engine.support.hierarchical.SameThreadHierarchicalTestExecutorService.invokeAll(SameThreadHierarchicalTestExecutorService.java:41)
    at org.junit.platform.engine.support.hierarchical.NodeTestTask.lambda$executeRecursively$6(NodeTestTask.java:155)
    at org.junit.platform.engine.support.hierarchical.ThrowableCollector.execute(ThrowableCollector.java:73)
    at org.junit.platform.engine.support.hierarchical.NodeTestTask.lambda$executeRecursively$8(NodeTestTask.java:141)
    at org.junit.platform.engine.support.hierarchical.Node.around(Node.java:137)
    at org.junit.platform.engine.support.hierarchical.NodeTestTask.lambda$executeRecursively$9(NodeTestTask.java:139)
    at org.junit.platform.engine.support.hierarchical.ThrowableCollector.execute(ThrowableCollector.java:73)
    at org.junit.platform.engine.support.hierarchical.NodeTestTask.executeRecursively(NodeTestTask.java:138)
    at org.junit.platform.engine.support.hierarchical.NodeTestTask.execute(NodeTestTask.java:95)
    at org.junit.platform.engine.support.hierarchical.SameThreadHierarchicalTestExecutorService.submit(SameThreadHierarchicalTestExecutorService.java:35)
    at org.junit.platform.engine.support.hierarchical.HierarchicalTestExecutor.execute(HierarchicalTestExecutor.java:57)
    at org.junit.platform.engine.support.hierarchical.HierarchicalTestEngine.execute(HierarchicalTestEngine.java:54)
    at org.junit.platform.launcher.core.EngineExecutionOrchestrator.execute(EngineExecutionOrchestrator.java:147)
    at org.junit.platform.launcher.core.EngineExecutionOrchestrator.execute(EngineExecutionOrchestrator.java:127)
    at org.junit.platform.launcher.core.EngineExecutionOrchestrator.execute(EngineExecutionOrchestrator.java:90)
    at org.junit.platform.launcher.core.EngineExecutionOrchestrator.lambda$execute$0(EngineExecutionOrchestrator.java:55)
    at org.junit.platform.launcher.core.EngineExecutionOrchestrator.withInterceptedStreams(EngineExecutionOrchestrator.java:102)
    at org.junit.platform.launcher.core.EngineExecutionOrchestrator.execute(EngineExecutionOrchestrator.java:54)
    at org.junit.platform.launcher.core.DefaultLauncher.execute(DefaultLauncher.java:114)
    at org.junit.platform.launcher.core.DefaultLauncher.execute(DefaultLauncher.java:86)
    at org.junit.platform.launcher.core.DefaultLauncherSession$DelegatingLauncher.execute(DefaultLauncherSession.java:86)
    at org.junit.platform.launcher.core.SessionPerRequestLauncher.execute(SessionPerRequestLauncher.java:53)
    at com.intellij.junit5.JUnit5IdeaTestRunner.startRunnerWithArgs(JUnit5IdeaTestRunner.java:71)
    at com.intellij.rt.junit.IdeaTestRunner$Repeater.startRunnerWithArgs(IdeaTestRunner.java:33)
    at com.intellij.rt.junit.JUnitStarter.prepareStreamsAndStart(JUnitStarter.java:220)
    at com.intellij.rt.junit.JUnitStarter.main(JUnitStarter.java:53)
Caused by: java.lang.IllegalArgumentException: Log types cannot be injected, please use DeferredLogFactory
    at org.springframework.boot.context.config.ConfigDataLocationResolvers.lambda$new$0(ConfigDataLocationResolvers.java:64)
    at org.springframework.core.io.support.SpringFactoriesLoader$ArgumentResolver.lambda$ofSupplied$3(SpringFactoriesLoader.java:585)
    at org.springframework.core.io.support.SpringFactoriesLoader$ArgumentResolver$1.resolve(SpringFactoriesLoader.java:601)
    at org.springframework.core.io.support.SpringFactoriesLoader$ArgumentResolver.lambda$and$0(SpringFactoriesLoader.java:551)
    at org.springframework.core.io.support.SpringFactoriesLoader$ArgumentResolver$1.resolve(SpringFactoriesLoader.java:601)
    at java.base/java.util.stream.ReferencePipeline$3$1.accept(ReferencePipeline.java:197)
    at java.base/java.util.Spliterators$ArraySpliterator.forEachRemaining(Spliterators.java:992)
    at java.base/java.util.stream.AbstractPipeline.copyInto(AbstractPipeline.java:509)
    at java.base/java.util.stream.AbstractPipeline.wrapAndCopyInto(AbstractPipeline.java:499)
    at java.base/java.util.stream.AbstractPipeline.evaluate(AbstractPipeline.java:575)
    at java.base/java.util.stream.AbstractPipeline.evaluateToArrayNode(AbstractPipeline.java:260)
    at java.base/java.util.stream.ReferencePipeline.toArray(ReferencePipeline.java:616)
    at java.base/java.util.stream.ReferencePipeline.toArray(ReferencePipeline.java:622)
    at org.springframework.core.io.support.SpringFactoriesLoader$FactoryInstantiator.resolveArgs(SpringFactoriesLoader.java:387)
    at org.springframework.core.io.support.SpringFactoriesLoader$FactoryInstantiator.instantiate(SpringFactoriesLoader.java:377)
    at org.springframework.core.io.support.SpringFactoriesLoader.instantiateFactory(SpringFactoriesLoader.java:228)
    ... 95 common frames omitted
```

Upgraded Spring Boot version and performed other needed changes (updated checkstyle plugin, moved to jakarta EE, replaced deprecations). Code is compiling, however spring context is not starting up due to above mentioned issue.

Comment: could you add  what dependencies do you use?

Comment: spring-boot-starter-actuator:jar:3.0.0
spring-boot-starter-data-jpa:jar:3.0.0
spring-boot-starter-security:jar:3.0.0
spring-boot-starter-web:jar:3.0.0
spring-cloud-starter-config:jar:3.1.5
spring-cloud-starter-netflix-eureka-client:jar:3.1.4
spring-kafka:jar:3.0.0
mapstruct:jar:1.5.2.Final
jolokia-core:jar:1.7.1
postgresql:jar:42.5.1:runtime
lombok:jar:1.18.24
commons-collections4:jar:4.4
logstash-logback-encoder:jar:6.4
springdoc-openapi-ui:jar:1.6.9
dd-trace-api:jar:0.80.0

Comment: transitive dependencies coming through internal libs:

jakarta.persistence-api:jar:3.1.0, jackson-annotations:jar:2.14.1, hibernate-core:jar:5.3.10.Final, javax.persistence-api:jar:2.2, jboss-transaction-api_1.2_spec:jar:1.1.1.Final, javax.activation-api:jar:1.2.0, validation-api:jar:2.0.1.Final, slf4j-api:jar:2.0.4, commons-lang3:jar:3.12.0, jackson-datatype-jsr310:jar:2.14.1, hibernate-validator:jar:8.0.0.Final, jakarta.validation-api:jar:3.0.2, 
spring-cloud-commons:jar:3.1.5
jjwt-api:jar:0.11.5
jjwt-impl:jar:0.11.5
jjwt-jackson:jar:0.11.5
bcprov-jdk18on:jar:1.71:runtime

Comment: My concern eventually is using version 2021.0.5 of spring-cloud-dependencies that allegedly is not compatible with Spring Boot 3 and 2022.0.0 is not officially released yet.

Comment: you can write about your solution to answers, it can helps to other developers

Answer (score 20):

Using Spring Cloud 2022.0.0 should fix the issue.

Comment: This was working prior to the holidays while it was still in libs-milestone -- seems like it doesn't any more...maybe since 2022.0.0 was released in [mid-December 2022](https://spring.io/blog/2022/12/16/spring-cloud-2022-0-0-codename-kilburn-has-been-released).  Is it still working for you?  Any ideas?

Comment: Okay...so we also had `spring-cloud-config-client` v3.1.2.  Upgrading it to v4.0.0 fixed the DeferredLog issue.

Answer (score 6):

```
<spring-cloud.version>2022.0.0</spring-cloud.version>
```

used to version for springboot 3.0.1 version and with java17 version.

I solved my problem.

Comment: How do you do this in gradle?

Answer (score 4):

If you have an incorrect version, some of your integration tests will fail with the error "unable to instantiate factory class ..." and you will not be able to start the spring application as well.

Here is the compatibility for Spring Boot 3 from Pivotal Spring Cloud Service Starter and native Spring Cloud Dependency.

| SCS Starters | Spring Cloud | Spring Boot |
| --- | --- | --- |
| 4.0.x | 2022.0.x | 3.0.x |

After this change with maven or gradle (with correction version), do a clean rebuild and you might encounter with a different error "fail to start" Spring Boot application like the following:

> No spring.config.import property has been defined
> Action: Add a
> spring.config.import=configserver: property to your configuration.

This means you are missing a config.  You might want to add a config / set your application.properties or .yml with something like the followings,

```
spring:
  config:
    import: "optional:configserver:"
```

or

```
cloud:
    config:
      enabled: false
```

Answer (score 1):

I faced the same issue with JDK17, spring-boot 3.0.5
So, I've updated the dependencies to match the new spring-boot version requirements to the following

Update the POM file

```
<dependency>
    <groupId>org.springframework.cloud</groupId>
    <artifactId>spring-cloud-starter-bootstrap</artifactId>
    <version>4.0.2</version>
</dependency>
<dependency>
    <groupId>org.springframework.cloud</groupId>
    <artifactId>spring-cloud-starter-config</artifactId>
    <version>4.0.2</version>
</dependency>
```

Update the spring cloud version.

```
<spring-cloud.version>2022.0.1</spring-cloud.version>
```

Update the properties to enable configuration url

```
spring.cloud.config.server.git.uri= URL
```

Or use the default configserver URL localhost:8888

```
spring.config.import=optional:configserver:
```

Or disable the config server

```
spring.config.enabled=false
```

For more details check the [spring documentation](https://docs.spring.io/spring-cloud-config/docs/current/reference/html/)

Comment: ```<dependency>
    <groupId>org.springframework.cloud</groupId>
    <artifactId>spring-cloud-starter-bootstrap</artifactId>
    <version>4.0.2</version>
</dependency>```